# Renaming files using rename

Tags: linux, rename

I am trying to rename .srt files. The files presently have names such as this:

> StargateSG1.s02e19.One.False.Step.AC3.DVDRip.DivX-AMC.srt

I would like the resulting file to be :

> StargateSG1.s02e19.srt

After studying rename for awhile I came up with the command:

> rename -n 's/(\d{19})/$1.srt/' *.srt

Which is supposed to save the first 19 characters and remove the rest then appending .srt to the first 19 characters. It's not working and I'm stumped.
I have searched this out and can't find any help, as far as I can tell this should work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ rename -n 's/^(.{18}).*$/$1.srt/' *.srt
StargateSG1.s02e19.One.False.Step.AC3.DVDRip.DivX-AMC.srt renamed as StargateSG1.s02e19.srt
```

You had 2 problems:

1. `\d` stands for any digit, while you need `.` which is any character.
2. You didn't match the rest of the filename, so the replacement operation wouldn't have removed it.

Comment: Can you please explain the .*$  and the ^ ?

Comment: `.*` is any number of any characters. `^` is the start of input, `$` is the end of input, their purpose is to ensure that we match the whole input from start to end, instead of just a portion of the input.